# Compress image without saving it

Tags: c#, image, compression

I am using the following code to compress an image and it does a nice job but I want to use the compressed image not save it.  So right now I have to save the image then read it in again which is slow.  Is there a way of compressing it with out saving it.

```
    private void compress(System.Drawing.Image img, long quality, ImageCodecInfo codec)
    {
        EncoderParameters parameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
        parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, quality);
        img.Save("check1.jpg", codec, parameters);
    }

    private static ImageCodecInfo GetCodecInfo(string mimeType)
    {
        foreach (ImageCodecInfo encoder in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders())
            if (encoder.MimeType == mimeType)
                return encoder;
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
            string.Format("'{0}' not supported", mimeType));
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an [overload that takes a `Stream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142148(v=vs.110).aspx) so you can save it straight to a `MemoryStream` and won't need to save to disk/reload.

```
EncoderParameters parameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, quality);

var ms = new MemoryStream();
img.Save(ms, codec, parameters);

//Do whatever you need to do with the image
//e.g.
img = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

The reason you're getting the "Parameter not valid" exception you mention in the comments is because the image isn't being disposed of before you try to call `FromStream`, so you'll need to dispose it. Also, I don't know how you're calling this method, but you should probably update it to return the `MemoryStream`.

```
private MemoryStream compress(System.Drawing.Image img, long quality, ImageCodecInfo codec)
{
    EncoderParameters parameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
    parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, quality);

    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    img.Save(ms, codec, parameters);
    return ms;
}

public void MyMethod()
{
    MemoryStream ms;
    using(var img = Image.FromFile("myfilepath.img"))
    {
        ms = compress(img, /*quality*/, /*codec*/);
    }

    using(var compressedImage = Image.FromStream(ms))
    {
        //Use compressedImage
    }
}
```

Notice how I return `ms` from compress and capture it. Also, more importantly, how we wrap the initial `img` in a `using` statement which will dispose the file handle correctly, and *after* that gets disposed create the second  `compressedImage` which is also in a `using` so it will *also* get disposed of properly when you're done.

Comment: When it does the save I now get this: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: Parameter is not valid.

Comment: If you look at the link I provided, this overload doesn't throw an `ArgumentException`, only `ArgumentNullException` and `ExternalException`. Are you sure you're receiving an `ArgumentException`? Are you sure it's on the `img.Save` line?

Comment: It is the definitely the save line and this is copied from the screen  \An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: Parameter is not valid.

Comment: Oh, it's because the original `img` isn't getting disposed. I updated my answer with a more complete example, including `using` statements for proper disposal.