# Compress image without saving it -- in Java

Tags: java, image-compression

Is there a way, in Java, to compute what the size of a compressed image will be w/o saving the image? (This will be used to determine the quality necessary to compress an image to a specific size.)

[Something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33393975/535275), but in Java instead of C#, and where the Stream can be a dead end.

Comment: Java's `MemoryStream` equivalent is `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Once you compress the image you can [write it to that stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write(java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.OutputStream)), get the size in bytes and discard the stream.

Comment: @BackSlash: I fear the answer is to write my own, but is there a stream I could use that wouldn't even save the data in memory but still allow me to determine what the size *would* have been?

Comment: @ScottHunter AFAIK no default way. But you could extend InputStream and instead of storing the bytes just count the length. Should be painless

Comment: @MatthewKerian: You mean *Out*putStream, right?

Comment: @ScottHunter Yeah, my bad

Comment: @ScottHunter Updated it with a simple implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple implementation.

```
public class LengthCounterOutputStream extends OutputStream{

    private int byteCounter = 0;

    @Override
    public void write(int b){
        byteCounter++;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(@NotNull byte[] b){
        this.write(b, 0, b.length);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(@NotNull byte[] b, int off, int len){
        byteCounter += len;
    }

    public int getByteCounter(){
        return byteCounter;
    }
}
```